# Django - How to use render_to_response whose request is $http

Tags: python, django, angularjs, http, render

In Django it is possible to use the render_to_response when the request comes from a $http of angularjs?
Example:

```
<!--proposta.html-->
<div ng-app='App' ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="submit" value="Gerar" ng-click="post_dados(x)">
</div>
```

This button passes a parameter to the function in post_dados() in file data_app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', []);
function MyCtrl($scope,$http,$sce) {
   $scope.retorno
   $scope.post_dados = function (lista) {
       $http({
           method:'POST',
           url:'/send_proposta/',
           data: lista,
           headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
       }).success(function(retorno){
           $scope.retorno=retorno
         })
   }
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^send_proposta/$', 'mge.core.views.send_proposta'),)
```

views.py

```
def send_proposta(request):
    proposta_tratada, header = tratar_proposta(request.POST)
    if proposta_tratada=='erro':
        json_erro=simplejson.dumps('Incorrect reporting of the Proposal, fill again')
        return HttpResponse(json_erro, content_type ="application/json")
    else:
        table_edit=valido(proposta_tratada, header)
        return render_to_response('rateio.html', {'x' :  table_edit})
```

The return HttpResponse sends the message to the `.success (function (return) {...}` put the `return render_to_response ('rateio.html', {x:. table_edit})` does not send the information to the rateio.html, just goes to the rateio.html if the source is a form.

It is possible to use the render_to_response with the $http? If possible, how could I do it?

Comment: Django doesn't care where the request comes from, so the answer is "yes".

Comment: And how could I do, as already tried in many ways and can not render the page rateio.html

Comment: What happens?  Have you checked e.g. the Chrome dev tools to see what response your view is sending back?  There is not enough information in your question to help at the moment.

Comment: When the parameters are not correct, the Ajax request returns in proposta.html page `Incorrect reporting of the Proposal, fill again`.
However, when the information is correct, I want to render the data in rateio.html page, only he is not rendering, he is entering all the html code on the page in text format in proposta.html page.

Comment: It sounds like Django is giving you what you asked for: it has rendered the `rateio.html` page and sent it back to you. The problem seems to be that your javascript is not doing what you want it to when it receives the html from Django.  You want to _replace_ the current page with `rateio.html`?

Comment: That's it !!! I want to replace the current page with rateio.html!!!